# How to add LiDAR Intensity attribute to a point feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar, ascii, las

I need to convert LASD (ESRI LAS Dataset) to ASCII text file. I've export the data to point feature class (LAS to Multipoint), converted multipart to single part and calculate X Y and Z.My first question is -  How do I add the LiDAR Intensity attribute to the point feature class ? My Second question Is There a better way to convert LASD to ASCII ? i tried the tool las2txt at [LasTools](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/) but I still looking for an answer for my first question

Answer (score 3):

Try [las2txt](http://www.liblas.org/utilities/las2txt.html) in the [libLAS](http://www.liblas.org/index.html) library.

> las2txt allows you to output ASRPS LAS files into ASCII text.

Example:

> `$ las2txt -i lidar.las -o lidar.txt -parse xyz`
>
> converts LAS file to ASCII and places the x, y, and z coordinate of each point at the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd entry of each line. the entries are separated by a space.

There is also the [Feature Class Z to ASCII](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q90000000m000000) tool under 3D Analyst-Conversion, but since you have the LAS files it would probably be easier to use las2txt.

Comment: Thanks blah for your contribution, I've updated my question, I'm looking for way using ArcMap only